# Selenium is not keeping the window open even after changing the options

Tags: python, selenium

Ive been trying to keep my selenium window open but even with the options changes the window closes immediately after finishing the test.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')



driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Just an update to what i've noticed. The window only closes automatically when i run it through Visual Studio Code, if i were to run it through IDLE for example the window stays open fine. Is it a configuration with the visual IDE itself?

Comment: That is expected behavior. put `time.sleep(5)` after `driver.get("https://google.com")` and see if that helps

Comment: So the time function does work but is there a way to keep it open until i close it myself?

Comment: Turn your `teardown` to false. Plus it's better if you use `OOP` and create a `class`. With a class for your driver you can alter the `__exit__` function to apply `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()` to work only if the value of `teardown` is `true`.